# Acción en botones generados por codigo

Tags: java, android-studio

estoy intentando que unos botones creados en el código se modifiquen al clicar en ellos.
El problema que tengo es que al clicar en los primeros 2 botones solo se me modifica el ultimo botón. Se os ocurre alguna solución?

Dejo aquí el cogido:

```
GridLayout lContenedor;
Button boton;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    lContenedor = (GridLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearPrincipal);
    agregarBotones(10);
}

public void agregarBotones(int elementos){
    for (int i= 0; i<elementos; i++){
        boton = new Button(this);
        boton.setId(i);
        boton.findViewById(i).setOnClickListener(this);
        lContenedor.addView(boton);
    }
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case 0:
            boton.setText("hola");
            break;
        case 1:
            boton.setText("adios");
            break;
            default:
                break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Explicacion:** Cuando inicializaste tu

```
Button boton;
```

y luego creas los botones

```
 boton = new Button(this);
        boton.setId(i);
        boton.findViewById(i).setOnClickListener(this);
```

te quedo referencia al ultimo `Button` que creaste en el for

**Posible Solucion:**

```
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
boton =  (Button)v //casteo a boton a la vista a la que hago click 
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case 0:
                boton.setText("hola");
                break;
            case 1:
                boton.setText("adios");
                break;
                default:
                    break;
        }
    }
```